# class GeoIP not found

Tags: laravel

I have installed GeoIP for laravel in my laravel app as instructed on: https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip

but when i try to fetch vistors location using in controller as so:

```
$location = GeoIP::getLocation();
```

I get class GeoIP not dound exception though I have included the GeoIP class in controller as:

```
use GeoIP;
```

This is my composer.json require array:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "matriphe/imageupload": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev",
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "~1.3",
         "jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl": "1.3.*",
        "cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch": "^1.0",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^2.1",
        "torann/geoip": "0.2.*@dev"


    },
```

my service providers array:

```
'providers' => array(

    'Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPServiceProvider',

)
```

To aliases array:

```
'aliases' => array(

    'GeoIP' => 'Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPFacade',

)
```

In short I have correctly installed the package. I have also tried to inlcude the GeoIP class as:

```
use Torann\GeoIP;
```

But still the class cannot be found. Any help please.

Comment: Try to run `composer dumpauto` command and use `use Torann\GeoIP;` then.

Comment: I have tried  what Alexy have suggested but I gain get Class 'Torann\GeoIP' not found

Comment: Have u ran the command `composer install` to install the package?

Comment: yes, I had done so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5.x, try to include the provider like this:

```
Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPServiceProvider::class,
```

And the alias like this:

```
'GeoIP' => Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPFacade::class,
```

Run a `composer update` after if necessary.

Then in your controller, make sure to use GeoIP:

```
use GeoIP as GeoIP;
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much. The issuer with my aliases. I had added 'GeoIP' => Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPFacade instead of 'GeoIP' => Torann\GeoIP\GeoIPFacade::class. This fixes the issue.